# Data updated in the Excel sheet, but name was not retrieved from the dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I am a new learner and beginner in this Excel VBA. 
I have created one VBA program to register and update patient's information or data for a health screening test. Using the same sheet (register) to store the registered and updated data, I was able to retrieve the previous registered/updated data based on dropdown selection (cmbName), I referred from this site for the update functionality https://yodalearning.com/tutorials/update-delete-using-excel-vba-userform-vba-userform/.
However, while updating, the rest of the data is updated and reflected in the respective cells, but the name is not retrieved and the cell for the name (C2) is blank.

Here is my code (for update):

```
Private Sub BT_Update_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

If Me.cmbName.Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Select name!", vbExclamation, "Name"
  Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("register").Activate
'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TB_RegNum.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TB_Date.Value

'Here where I failed to retrieve the name
'Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Me.cmbName.Value 'Name populated but new value not updated
'Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = cmbName.Value    'Name populated but new value not updated
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TB_NRIC.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TB_Address.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = TB_Phone.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = TB_Gender
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TB_Race.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = TB_Height.Value
```

And below is for dropdown (cmbName):

```
Private Sub cmbName_Change()

If Me.cmbName.Value = "" Then
MsgBox "Select Name!", vbExclamation, "Name"
Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next

Me.TB_Date.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("B2:B1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_RegNum.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("A2:A1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_NRIC.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("D2:D1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_Address.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("E2:E1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_Phone.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("F2:F1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_Gender.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("G2:G1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_Race.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("H2:H1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
Me.TB_Height.Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(Range("I2:I1000"), WorksheetFunction.Match(cmbName.Value, Range("C2:C1000"), 0))
```

Comment: There is no apparent reason why your remmed-out code (either line) shouldn't work. cmbName.Value <> "" as proven by the test at the top of your code. Therefore, if cmbName.Value doesn't arrive at the "Register" the reason must be elsewhere. The fault might be in your test, not your code. How do you generate the drop-down list in cmbName? What is the value of *emptyRow* when "C2 is blank"? Look closely at the logic of your test, where the data come from and how they are transmitted.

Comment: You are activating the "Register" and then referring to the ActiveSheet (default) in the rest of the code. That isn't good. I never do that, so I don't know. Could it be that your code writes to another sheet, or not at all, and what you see in row 2 was there all along? Repeat the test with *emptyRow* being >2

Comment: The dropdown is generated using the Private Sub cmbName_Change() using the Index-Match function. Previously the requirement was to create separate sheet for register and update, then later it changed to use only one sheet, that is why both register and update are in the same sheet with different userforms (register and update).

Comment: Please add the code of *Sub cmbName_Change* to your question. It sounds strange that the drop-down should be loaded only **after** you make a selection. This might be the source of the problem. One would expect that the drop-down be set when the form is initialised and not changed thereafter.

Comment: I have updated the code and try something else. I put this line "Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = cmbName.Value" below the "Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = TB_Height.Value" and now it works. But still did not get the logic behind that, I guess it is related to what you have said earlier @Variatus.

Comment: Great! Glad you got it working. Please post your final code as an answer and mark it as "Accepted". Very roughly speaking, a form is like a class and a worksheet is like another class. You can freely access any class from a standard code module but when you access one class from another there are problems. The one you found might have been avoided if you write to the sheet by a procedure in a standard code module which you call from your user forms's code sheet. Anyway, it works now, and that's what counts.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and idea @Variatus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub BT_Update_Click()
Dim emptyRow As Long

If Me.cmbName.Value = "" Then
  MsgBox "Select name!", vbExclamation, "Name"
  Exit Sub
End If

Sheets("register").Activate
'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Transfer information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = TB_RegNum.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TB_Date.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TB_NRIC.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = TB_Address.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 6).Value = TB_Phone.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 7).Value = TB_Gender
Cells(emptyRow, 8).Value = TB_Race.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 9).Value = TB_Height.Value
'Bring this line to the bottom and it works!
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = cmbName.Value
```